# L'Hôpital's rule - can the functions fluctuate between infinity and minus infinity?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

The Wikipedia page of L'Hôpital's rule says:
"Thus the rule applies to situations in which the ratio of the derivatives has a finite or infinite limit, **but not to situations in which that ratio fluctuates permanently as x gets closer and closer to c**."

But then it says: (Look at what is written after "or")
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSnri.png

So are f(x) and g(x) allowed to fluctuate between infinity and minus infinity?

Comment: If $\lim_{x \to c} |f(x)| = \infty$ (for a continuous real-valued function) then either $\lim_{x \to c} f(x) = +\infty$ or $\lim_{x \to c} f(x) = -\infty$. A “fluctuation” between plus and minus infinity is not possible in that case.

Comment: [Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/42969)  Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. – For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: We could ask this question where $f,g$ have complex values and $\lim_{x\to c}|f(x)| = \infty, \lim_{x\to c}|g(x)| = \infty$. Such as  $f(x) = xe^{ix}$.

Answer (score 0):

The assumption that $f$ and $g$ do not "fluctuate" is useless: see the [proof in the page of Wikipedia you mention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule#General_proof) (or in [that page of Wikiversity in french](https://fr.wikiversity.org/wiki/Fonctions_d%27une_variable_r%C3%A9elle/D%C3%A9rivabilit%C3%A9#Th%C3%A9or%C3%A8mes_sur_la_d%C3%A9rivation)). Only their *ratio* is supposed to have a limit (hence not "fluctuate").

Anyway, this assumption on $g$ is redundant because if $\lim_c|g|=\infty$, then on some neighborhood of $c$, $g$ does not vanish hence (by continuity) $g$ is of constant sign, so that (as said by Martin R in the comments) either $\lim_cg=+\infty$ or $\lim_cg=-\infty$.

As for $f$, the assumption $\lim_c|f|=\infty$ is in fact not needed and $|f|$ may even have no limit (e.g. $c=+\infty,f(x)=x\sin x,g(x)=x^3$).